# How to convert docx to pdf using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.7, document-conversion

I want to display a preview of files uploaded by a users.
For this reason, I have to convert docx-files to pdf using python 3.7.

When looking for a library to do the job I found the following:

- **pdfminer**, but it only supports python 2.7
- **comtypes**, but it is a library for Windows only

Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You might want to have a look at [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).